# jquery set color of one table row

Tags: jquery, colors

I need to be able to change the color of a single table row in jquery to red, and set all the others listed as white.

I've set each one with a class eg `<tr class=row1>`, `<tr class=row2>`.
The javascript variable for the current row id that should be colored is `id`.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: until you clarify your question don't go anywhere, edit your question to get answer.

Comment: You need to clarify your question!

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/oyicoy/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$('table tr').eq(  ).css({color:'red'}).siblings().css({color:'white'});
//               ^^-- set here the index number of the row you desire to change color
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr:eq(0)', 'table')
    .siblings('color', '#fff') // select all tr except first one and change color
    .andSelf() // target to the first one
    .css('color', '#f00'); ​​​// change color of first tr
```

You can change index within `:eq(index)`  according to  your target element.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bLA6F/)**

Comment: thanks, how would i specify what specific table I want this to happen on?

Comment: @user1022585 you can loop through each table using `$.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using css,

for e.g. if you want to set the 3 row with class="row1" to red than,

```
 .row1:nth-child(3){
     background-color: red;
  }
```